# android check file exists Object File

Tags: android, io

I have an object file which I can open and read no problems, opening the file as below

```
inputStream =  openFileInput("ObsOEvents");   
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(inputStream);
```

BUT if I try to check if the file exists before attempting the open it reports as doesn't exist.

```
File file = new File("ObsOEvents");  
if(!file.exists())
```

I would like to check first rather than rely on an exception being thrown. I presume there is some way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You should create the `File` object you want to check with `new File(context.getFilesDir(), "ObsOEvents")`. [`openFileInput()` reads files from that directory](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getFilesDir%28%29).